# adding rows to table layout error

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I am creating a `TableLayout` and programmatically adding views to it.When I add `TextView` and  Image it is working properly.When I try to add `RadioGroup` with `RadioButtons` it is showing errors.

In my Xml layout I have tablelayout under scroll view and below is my Java code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
 import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
 import android.widget.TableLayout;
 import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
public class DamnitActivity extends Activity {
TableLayout makeit;
ArrayList list_name;
int color_blue = -16776961;
int color_gray = -7829368;
int color_black = -16777216;
int color_white = -1;

final int CHECK_BUTTON_ID = 982301;
int ids_check[];
boolean bool_check[];

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    makeit = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    list_name = new ArrayList();

    list_name.add("Close");
    list_name.add("Cristiano");
    list_name.add("David");
    list_name.add("Fernando");
    list_name.add("Messi");
    list_name.add("Kaka");
    list_name.add("Wayne");
    list_name.add("ghse");
    list_name.add("gouse");
    list_name.add("ghuse");
    list_name.add("ghous");
    list_name.add("ouse");
    list_name.add("use");
    list_name.add("e");
    list_name.add("eff");
    list_name.add("euyr");
    list_name.add("ejjyytuty");
    list_name.add("madre");
    list_name.add("yuir");
    list_name.add("eyrty");
    list_name.add("etytr");
    list_name.add("ewrrtt");
    bool_check = new boolean[list_name.size()];
    ids_check = new int[list_name.size()];
    createTableRows();

    }

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){ 

    }

    public void createTableRows()
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < list_name.size(); i++)
    {

    TextView tv_name = new TextView(this);
    Button btn_check = new Button(this);
    ImageView img_line = new ImageView(this);
    RadioGroup mgroup=new RadioGroup(this); 
    RadioButton newRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
    newRadioButton.setText("hi");

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
            RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mgroup.addView(newRadioButton, 0, layoutParams);



    tv_name.setText((CharSequence) list_name.get(i));
    tv_name.setTextColor(color_blue);
    tv_name.setTextSize(30);
    tv_name.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    tv_name.setWidth(150);

    btn_check.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(30, 30));
    btn_check.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.small_checkbox_unchecked);

    img_line.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));
    img_line.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.separater_line);

    makeit.addView(tv_name);
    makeit.addView(btn_check);
    makeit.addView(mgroup);


    int id = i + CHECK_BUTTON_ID;
    btn_check.setId(id);
    ids_check[i] = id;

    btn_check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int j = 0; j < ids_check.length; j++)
    {
    Button btn_check_1 = (Button) findViewById(ids_check[j]);
    if(v.getId() == ids_check[j])
    if(bool_check[j])
    {
    btn_check_1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.small_checkbox_unchecked);
    bool_check[j] = false;
    }
    else
    {
    btn_check_1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.small_checkbox_checked);
    bool_check[j] = true;
    }
    }
    }
    });

    }
    }
    }
```

And Error is:

> 2-10 11:40:24.120: E/AndroidRuntime(995): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pace.damnit/com.pace.damnit.DamnitActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Which line are you getting NullPointerException in?

Comment: it is showing error in the 115 line which is  makeit.addView(tv_name);  but i am new to this environment and may be i couldn't point it out exactly also and this is

Comment: 12-10 12:22:20.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):at com.pace.damnit.DamnitActivity.createTableRows(DamnitActivity.java:115)
: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):  at com.pace.damnit.DamnitActivity.onCreate(DamnitActivity.java:76)
: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-10 12:22:20.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely **makeit** TableLayout object is null

Comment: but when i run the same code without adding radio group it was running properly then what could be the reason?